# interact ipywidget min and max

Tags: python, ipywidgets

I would like to set a min and max value for `interact` from `ipywidgets`.
[This](http://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Using%20Interact.html#Basic-interact) is all I could find concerning the use of `interact`. I am essentially trying to do the first example, however with a specified range of values for the slider.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to your question is [further down in the docs](http://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Using%20Interact.html#Widget-abbreviations). Quoting the example for setting up min/max:

> interact(f, x=widgets.IntSlider(min=-10,max=30,step=1,value=10))

Comment: I thought I scoured through the entirety of the docs -- apparently not. Thanks!